# Question about orbit of $S^1$ action on symplectic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In Salamon&McDuff's book, they claim

> Denote by $\alpha_X \in H_1(M,Z)$ the homology class which is
> represented by the orbits of the $S^1$ action. All these orbits are
> homologous because M is connected.

I wonder why.

Comment: Pick points in two nearby orbits and join them by a path. Act on that path. To get from nearby to general, use the usual connectedness game.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks a lot. Could you say more about 'Act on that path'?

Comment: The action of $S^1$ on the arc (the path) gives a homology between the orbits of the endpoints. Why did I say nearby?

Comment: I think I understand it, thank you so much. @Ted Shifrin

Comment: If you want to write a complete answer, do so and let know :)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I shall try to do it, but I am new to this part, I am not sure I can finish it. I just get the intuition of what you mean.

Comment: Up to you. I’ll help if you get stuck a bit.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thank you so much